# Why is my except block being jumped over?

Tags: python

I'm working on try/except. Every time I run a piece of code from a textbook, the exception is raised fine. Once I run my own though, the exception I've input won't raise.

```
while True:
    try:
        yes_or_no = input("Would you like to play a game?")
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, this is a yes or no question. ")
        continue
    else:
        break

if yes_or_no == "yes":
    print("Awesome")
else:
    print("Oh ok ")
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with this code? You can put in anything to an input, like `12234332434` or `sasdfsdkfnnsd` and it won't give a ValueError.

Comment: `input()` accepts (almost) anything, and will convert that to a string as output. There is no yes/no input() function, so there is no ValueError. I don't know where you got this idea/syntax, but it's non-existent. (Almost anything, since something control-C will likely interrupt your program.)

Comment: There is no ValueError and no exception :)

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing a `bool()` around the input?

Answer (score 0):

The except does not get raised because you are creating a str `yes_or_no` and assigning it to whatever the input buffer takes in. This will work for any value, the proper way to achieve what you're trying to achieve is like this:

```
yes_words = ["yes", "ye", "y", "ok"] #However many you want
no_words = ["n", "no"]

# No need for try: except: block in here
while True:
    yes_or_no = input("Would you like to play a game?")
    if (yes_or_no.lower() in yes_words or yes_or_no.lower() in no_words):
        break
    else:
        yes_or_no = None # Important that you void the input before continuing, otherwise its an infinite loop
        continue

if (yes_or_no.lower() in yes_words):
    print("Awesome")
else:
    print("Oh ok ")
```

Comment: Nitpick: no need for parentheses around an if-clause: Python can do without, and it only clutters the code. `if a == b` and the like is fine.

Comment: Also, you do not need to "void" the input, because `yes_or_no` is immediately overridden with the new input. In fact, you don't need the whole `else` clause there: shaves three lines off of the code.

Comment: This is first time in four months I wrote in python :P

Comment: What @00 said. And - (1.) the `if` clause can be reduced to `yes_or_no.lower() in yes_words + no_words` but that's optional. (2.) works better if `yes_words` and `no_words` are sets instead of lists; but that's also an optional change.